# ASP.NET C# - Redirect After Inserted Record

Tags: asp.net

I perform and insert new record, this code below works for for inserting. After that, I want to redirect to another page using window.parent.location with the ID (ProposalID) that I used in the insert.

```
private void ExecuteInsert(string ProposedID, string CreatedBy, string Note)
    {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    string sql = "INSERT INTO MDF_ProposedNote (ProposedID, Note, CreatedBy) 
    VALUES "
                + " (@ProposedID, @Note, @CreatedBy)";

    try
    {

            conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[3];

        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ProposedID", SqlDbType.Int, 10);
            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Note", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2000);
            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.Int, 10);

        param[0].Value = ProposedID;
        param[1].Value = Note;
        param[2].Value = CreatedBy;

        for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Insert Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        Response.Write("<script>window.parent.location = 
        'ProposalItemView.aspx?ProposedID='"<%=ProposedID%>";</script>");
    }
    }
```

This is where I and to redirect to another page + RecordID

```
Response.Write("<script>window.parent.location = 
'ProposalItemView.aspx?ProposedID='"<%=ProposedID%>";</script>");
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably  want

```
Response.Redirect(string.format("~/ProposalItemView.aspx?ProposedID={0}", ProposedID), true);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried, and getting this error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '{0}' to data type int." How can I convert it to INT?

Comment: Thanks @DanielA, but I need to use window.parent.location to redirect because I am using an Iframe for insert. I tried this, but not working "Response.Write(string.Format("<script>window.parent.location = 'ProposalItemView.aspx?ProposedID={0}';</script>", ProposedID), true);"

Comment: I got it, works now "Response.Write("<script>window.parent.location = 'ProposalItemView.aspx?ProposedID=" + ProposedID + "';</script>");". Thanks!